# How to iterate through options of select and get the correspond id?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to iterate through all option of select and get the option that have the same id of a variable. An example is better:

**SELECT STRUCTURE:**

```
<select id='operators'>
    <option value='0'>Harrison</option>
    <option value='1'>Julian</option>
</select>
```

**CODE:**

```
var operator_id = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < $('select#operators option').length; i++) {
    if ($('select#operators option')[i].val() == 1) {
        alert("Found!");
        //Here the code for select automatically in operator the option found
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e7pw3p4h/)

How you can see I want to get the option that have the same id of my variable value. After it I want to select automatically the select found in `operators`. So in this case will be show: `Julian` as selected value.

But I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[i].val is not a function

what is wrong?

Comment: `$('select#operators option')[i].value` or `$('select#operators option').eq(i).val()`

Comment: @Dillinger please note that if your entire intent was to just make the selected option be the one found, you didn't need to iterate at all. This is what's known as an "XY problem" - "I have a problem X and I believe Y is the solution, but I can't make Y work". The issue is that Y is not the solution, and just asking directly how to do X would have gotten you better answers sooner [or just pointed you at the other numerous questions about how to do this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Wrap your code in `$(function(){ ... });` wait for DOM Ready event.
- `$('select#operators option')[i]` is not a jquery object but a DOM element, so use `.value` instead

  ```
  $(function () {

    var operator_id = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < $('select#operators option').length; i++) {
      if ($('select#operators option')[i].value == 1) {
          alert("Found!");
          //Here the code for select automatically in operator the option found
      }
    }
  });
  ```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/e7pw3p4h/2/)

To set it as selected option instead of `alert` use

```
$('select#operators option')[i].selected = true;
```

Comment: _please_ don't put stuff about `$(function() {...})` in your answer unless the OP's question specifically suggests that it's missing.

Comment: And if I want change the option selected as the option found?

Comment: See updated answer.. use `$('select#operators option')[i].selected = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Using bracket notation on a jQuery object returns you the DOMElement at that index, not another jQuery object, so the `value()` method does not exist on that object. You instead need to use `eq()`:

```
var operator_id = 1;
for(var i = 0; i < $('select#operators option').length; i++) {
    if ($('select#operators option').eq(i).val() == 1)  {
        alert("Found!");
        //Here the code for select automatically in operator the option found
    }
}
```

Better yet, you can avoid the need for a loop at all:

```
var $option = $('#operators option[value="' + operator_id + '"]')
```

From there you can work with the `$option` as required.

If you want to set the selected `option` by its value, you can simply call `val()` on the parent `select` element:

```
var operator_id = 1;
$('#operators').val(operator_id);
```

Comment: And I'd also suggest to use `$('#operators option').each`

Comment: That would be better, but with the attribute selector you can avoid the loop completely.

Comment: And how I can set select option 'selected', by the option found? I've tried with: $("#operators select").val(operator_id);

Comment: I've never been a fan of concatenating stuff together to make value selectors - it just feels "wrong"

Comment: @Alnitak I'm the same. There's not much alternative for the attribute selector, bar `filter()`, but that is very slow.

Comment: @Dillinger You can use `.prop('selected', true);` to set the option as selected or `attr('selected', 'selected')`

Comment: @Dillinger you can set the selected option by calling `val()` on the select itself - no need to loop over the `option` elements at all. I updated my answer for you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan seems like an XY problem :(

Comment: Yeah it's heading that way, there's no need for any looping if all you want to do is select the option.

Answer (score 0):

The `[i]` element of a jQuery object is a native DOM element, not itself a jQuery object, therefore you cannot call `.val()` on it.

Try this instead - it'll be more efficient:

```
var opts = $('#operators option');
for (var i = 0, n = opts.length; i < n; ++i) {
    if (opts[i].value == operator_id) {
        // found!
    }
}
```

Note how jQuery is only called once and the result cached - everything else is done on that cached object, using native DOM properties as applicable.  There's also need to qualify your `#operators` selector with the node type - your element IDs are supposed to be unique.

All that said, if your intent is just to make a given option the selected value, you don't need to iterate over the options at all - just set the `.value` property of the `select` directly:

```
$('#operators').val(operator_id)
```